# Vector Object to location array

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
myLocation = (-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000)
SplinePoint.co = myLocation
```

Where `myLocation` is a blender Vector.

i.e. I want to assign a vector to a spline point's co attribute ...

in other words I want to convert a vector object into an array that matches the co attribute per:

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SplinePoint.html?highlight=splinepoint

Note: SplinePoint.co requires 4 values in its array (not sure why???)
This is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/iainm/Desktop/objects/dev_space.blend/Text", line 209, in <module>
ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Comment: Worth noting that the SplinePoint.co must be:
"Type: float array of 4 items in [-inf, inf], default (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)"
Per the docs linked in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert a vector to an array, you can just assign it to the location. A [vector](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector) is created from one value which is a set of three (or four) numbers, so you need the extra pair of parenthesis around the three values.

Any location, rotation and scale value can all take a vector or array as input values. All of the following work.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
obj.location = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000))
obj.location = [-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000]
obj.location = (-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000)
obj.rotation_euler = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000))
```

For bezier curves the same applies to it's curve points

```
# for bezier curve points
bezcurve = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']
SplinePoint = bezcurve.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0]
myLocation = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000))

SplinePoint.co = myLocation
SplinePoint.co = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000))
SplinePoint.co = [-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000]
SplinePoint.co = (-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000)
```

For nurbs paths each point is four values instead of three. The first three values are the x,y,z for the location as above while the fourth value (shown as w in the UI) controls the influence the point has on the curve, where a bezier point has handles that define the angle and strength of the curve leaving the point, a nurbs path only has an influence that pulls the path closer to the point the larger the value.

```
# for nurbs paths points
nurbpath = bpy.data.objects['NurbsPath']
SplinePoint = nurbpath.data.splines[0].points[0]
myLocation = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000, 1.0))

SplinePoint.co = myLocation
SplinePoint.co = Vector((-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000, 1.0))
SplinePoint.co = [-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000, 1.0]
SplinePoint.co = (-0.9056, -0.0628, -3.000, 1.0)
```

If you are getting a location as a vector from somewhere else you can use [`resize_4d()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.resize_4d) or the [`to_4d()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.to_4d) to use the location in the nurbs point. You can then alter the influence with either `SplinePoint.co[3] = 1.0` or `SplinePoint.co.w = 1.0`.

Comment: Ok, right, i don't have the word literally in there, just expressing what the blender console outputs when I print what myLocation is. 
The problem is that the array for the co of the spline  requires 4 values (check the doc linked in the Q) to confirm ...

Comment: got it, had to call to_4d() on the vector.

Comment: @gl2748 - right I should have noticed you where looking at nurbs points and not bezier points. I expanded the answer to clarify things.